# How to use EasyMock to mock a protected method?

Tags: java, protected, easymock

```
public class A{
    protected Integer methodA(String a){
        //some code is included;
        return new Integer(1);
    }
}
public class B extends B{
    String b = "AnyThing";
    methodA(b);
    //there are also other methods that will be tested
}
```

The following is partial test codes

```
B classUnderTest = createMockBuild(B.class).addMockedMethod(B.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodA(), String.class)).createMock;
expect(classUnderTest.methodA(anyObject(String.class))).andReturn(new Integer(1));
```

The second line of the second piece of code even cannot get through compile. Where is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jane, regarding your main question, the line

```
expect(classUnderTest.methodA(anyObject(String.class))).andReturn(new Integer(1));
```

will compile successfully if the `@Test` class is in the same `package` as your subject under test - in this case both classes `A` and `B` (if `class B extends A`). Protected instance methods are only visible to classes in the same package.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I made an inner class extends the class I want to test to solve this problem.